# How to combine aggregations in ElasticSearch/Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Let's imagine I am logging displays and clicks, say by cities.
I can aggregate those by countries and I can also compute grand totals.

Now I would like to compute click rates (clicks/displays) by cities, countries and I would also like to get a global click rate.
How can I do this?

It seems that I could use a scripted metric (I have not tried yet) but I would also like to expose these rates in Kibana.

It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I also want this feature. Kibana don't have this feature at this moment but maybe in the future version. please take a look at: 
https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/2646

update: I think you can use scripted fields please see for more info http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/kibana-4-beta-3-now-more-filtery/